# Grafico de barras

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy haciendo una gráfica de barras tengo este código que pinta las barras de la gráfica de color gris pero lo que quiero es que sea un color para cada barra por ejemplo para la barra uno=verde la dos=amarillo y la tres=rojo pero no se como ya que al poner otro color al lado de '#000000' me marca error

```
var areaChartData = {
                    labels  : ['Exploracion uno', 'Exploracion dos ', 'Exploracion 3'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label               : 'Electronics',
                        Color               :'#000000' ,
                        data                : [uno, dos, tres]
                    }]
                  }
```

Comment: Que libreria estas usando?

Comment: Estas usando Hightchart?

Comment: estoy usando Bar Chart